# How do I fix Unity3D crashing while using Notepad++?

Tags: unity-game-engine, notepad++

Everytime I use Notepad++ to edit a script, NP++ opens normally and works fine, but unity freezes and stops working. Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a known issue with Unity 5.5.  You'll have to find an IDE that plays better with Unity or edit your scripts without the use of Unity. Assuming you're using Windows, open Windows Explorer, find your scripts, edit them, save them, and go back to Unity to let it find your changes.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

do you setup a Notepad++ as your unity default script editor?

Comment: Yes!. The default one was monodevelop but it doesn't want to work at all, so i switched to Notepad++.

Comment: Never tried to use this two together, why don't you use Rider instead, it's pretty decent IDE from jetbrains and cross platform

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/. But for np++ problem, out of curiosity, can you check your task manager/activity monitor depends on OS, how much unity uses a CPU/memory when it's freezes.

Comment: Answering your question: I use windows 10 home edition 64-bit, Unity uses about 250 MB of the Memory and about 18% of the CPU. I usually use NP++ because it's easy and fast , unlike visual studio. It doesn't mean that I hate visual studio but I need a simple and a fast method to write a script.